# Program compiles but does not give correct value

Tags: c, windows

I am writing a calorie program for my C programming class and when it compiles I don't get the correct output.  For example I enter number of calories is 385 and get a total number of chips that exceed the calories I originally entered. I have included the code below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void calories(int total, int*pizza, int*chips, int*apple, int*mustard)

{
if (total >= 385)
    *pizza = (total - 385);
if (total >= 170)
    *chips = (total - (*pizza * 385))/170;
if (total >= 80)
    *apple = (total - (*pizza * 385) - (*chips * 170)) / 80;
if (total >= 5)
    *mustard = (total - (*pizza * 385) - (*chips * 170) - (*apple * 80)) / 5;

return;
}

int main(void)

{

int total, pizza, chips, apple, mustard;

printf("Enter the total whole number of calories you would like to eat for your meal: ");
scanf_s("%d", &total);
calories(total, &pizza, &chips, &apple, &mustard);
printf("\n Total= %d", total);
printf("\nSlices of pizza= %d", chips);
printf("\nBags of chips= %d", pizza);
printf("\nSlices of apple= %d",apple);
printf("\nTeaspoons of mustard= %d", mustard);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code doing a lot if integer arithmetic.  perhaps you wanted floating point.  IAC, post the "get a total number of chips that exceed the calories I originally entered" and why you think it is incorrect.

Comment: 1. Check the return value of `scanf_s` 2. Set the initial values to zero.

Comment: 1) What did you do? 2) What did you expect to happen? 3) What happened instead? You've answered 1 but not 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the pattern you should adopt

```
if (total >= 385) {
   *pizza = total / 385;
   total = total - *pizza * 385;
}
if (total >= 170) {
   *chips = total/170;
   total = total - *chips * 170;
}

etc...
```

i.e. keep total the running total

PS: You should really get a better diet

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!  A combination of all of these answers ended up solving my issue.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @EdHeal's comment, you are declaring your variables `pizza, chips, apple, mustard` on the stack. Stack variables in C are not automatically set to zero. You must initialize them to some value yourself.

You pass the address of the variables to the `calories()` function, but inside that function you do not assign a value to the variables *unless* the calorie count is greater than a certain number. So whenever the calorie count is "too low", the variables will have random values in them.

The simplest solution would be to initialize the variables at declaration:

```
int pizza = 0, chips = 0, apple = 0, mustard = 0;
```

A less simple, but actually better, idea would be to add an `else` clause to your statements in the `calorie` function, and set the target values to zero if you don't have another value for them:

```
if (total >= 385)
    *pizza = total / 385;
else
    *pizza = 0;

/* etc ... */
```

Answer (score 1):

On each if statement you are asking if total is greater yet you are not reducing value of total ... also looks like you wish to handle multiple quantities of pizza, etc yet you are not defining your if questions to accommodate this possibility

```
*pizza = total % 384;
total -= *pizza * 384;

*chips = total % 170;
total -= *chips * 170;

... do similar here for next purchase ...
... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Error in printf statements :

```
printf("\nSlices of pizza= %d", chips);
printf("\nBags of chips= %d", pizza);
```

For printing pizza you gave chips value and vice-versa.

```
if (total >= 385)
    *pizza = (total - 385);
```

Above you are not dividing total by 385 which may lead to wrong result.

Hope this will help.